# Rails ActiveRecord finding questions by tag in named scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, arel

I want the equivalent of SO search by tag, so I need an `exists` query but I also still need to left join on all tags. I've tried a couple of approaches and I'm out of ideas.

The Qustion - Tag relationship is through `has_and_belongs_to_many` both ways (i.e. I have a QuestionTags joiner table)

e.g.

`Question.join(:tags).where('tag.name = ?', tag_name).includes(:tags)`

I would expect this to do what I need but actually it just mashes up the `includes` with the `join` and I just end up with basically an inner join.

```
Question.includes(:tags)
   .where("exists (
               select 1 from questions_tags 
                where question_id = questions.id 
                  and tag_id = (select id 
                                  from tags 
                                 where tags.name = ?))", tag_name)
```

This fetches the correct results but a) is really ugly and b) gives a deprecation warning as again it seems to confuse the `includes` with the `join`:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) (one
>   of: questions, tags) that are referenced in a string SQL sn ippet. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")
> ```

Note I'm trying to write these as named scopes.

Let me know if the question isn't clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest I am confused why inner join is not good enough for You, can You please go more in detail why joining tags is not working for You?

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons because I need to display a list of all questions tagged with a particular tag, but within that list still I need to display all tags for each question, avoiding an N+1 lookup. E.g. click on the `sql` tag above to see the SO page that does what I need. With only the inner join the page would only show the `sql` tag under each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it. I know no built in syntax to do it. I have used an alternative before, You can do like this:

```
Question.include(:tags).where("questions.id IN (
#{ Question.joins(:tags).where('tags.name = ?', tag_name).select('questions.id').to_sql})")
```

You can also join this subquery to your questions table instead of using IN. Alternatively if You are not against adding gems and You are using Postgres, use this [gem](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2013/09/06/postgres_ext-adds-rank-and-common-table-expressions.html). 
It provides really neat syntax for advanced queries.

Comment: Thanks, this works but I again get the deprecation warning, is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference. I actually get this warning even with unrelated include, e.g. `Question.tagged("sql").includes(:votes)`. It seems to me a bug in rails, I'm having same problem on any query that has both a `join` and an `includes`.

Comment: Sorry don't have any Rails 4 projects cloned so can't play around myself. Maybe try submitting a ticket in Rails Github repo ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preload` instead of `includes`:

`Question.preload(:tags).where("exists ....`